# xlsx R: looping through list of files to check all sheet names; create a blank sheet if it does not exist

Tags: r, xlsx, purrr, readxl, openxlsx

I am attempting to write a loop through a file of Excel workbooks, checking the names of all sheets to ensure that each excel workbook has three sheet names in it ('sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3' - in any order). If one of those sheet names is missing, I want to create the missing sheet (blank) in the workbook missing the sheet.

1. I am currently stuck on making sure the workbooks' sheet names match (in the list 'result') - I tried the script below but 'correct_sheet' returns empty
2. For adding sheets, can addWorksheet (openxlsx) be used in a loop? Would map (purr) be better than a for loop / can map be applied to workbooks in a list?

I've never worked across multiple files like this and I'm open to any and all suggestions / approaches!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
'%notin%' <- Negate('%in%')


all_files <- list.files(path="./path/to/files'", pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = T)

#write files to a list to see the sheet names
result <- lapply(all_files, function(x) {
  all_sheets <- excel_sheets(x)  
}

#filter by which workbooks match criteria
correct_sheet <- lapply(result, FUN = function(x) {
  correct_sheet <- intersect(result, c('sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3') )
})

#Add worksheet in a loop
for (result %notin% correct_sheet){

  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm old skool. I like a for loop. That's what happens when you come from other languages!

So I'd be skipping all that lapply which doesn't explain what is going on and doing

```
new_data = "" # a placeholder for the data you will insert in an new empty sheet

for (file %in% all_files) {
# open the file and get it's sheets
sheets = excel_sheets(file)

# check if the file has the sheet you want
if ( "sheet1" %in% sheets) {
 # do nothing
} else {
# if not - create a sheet
xlsx::write.xlsx(new_data,
 file, # You may need to add the path? 
 sheetName="sheet1",
 append=TRUE)
} #if you are checking for all 3 sheets and adding any 3 missing, add another for loop?
```

The R purists will say this is slow and inefficient. My question would be how fast does it need to be? How readable does it need to be?

Comment: Thanks for your response - old skool works for me, this is defintiely a lot more streamlined than my apporach! I did have one question though, do you happen to know how to keep the new sheets blank? I used the "" placeholder and it still writes an x and 1 in the new sheet for some reason? I also tried other approaches using data.frame() as well to no avail

Comment: Good question. I will need to have a play. new_data was just something to quickly shove in there for demo purposes

Comment: It looks like there has to be something present.

Comment: You can use addSheet() but that requires you to load the workbook into memory first and then add it and then save it

Comment: I came to the same conclusion ;-/ No worries though, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
library(readxl)
all_files <- list.files(path="./path/to/files'", pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = T)
#Get sheet names
sheet_names <- lapply(all_files, excel_sheets)
#If less than 3 sheets
inds <- lengths(sheet_names) < 3

Map(function(x, y) {
  addsheets <- setdiff(c('sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3'), y)
  for(sh in addsheets) {
    xlsx::write.xlsx(data.frame(a = 1), x, sheetName=sh,append=TRUE)
  }
}, all_files[inds], sheet_names[inds])
```

For some reason passing an empty dataframe was giving me an error so I created a dummy dataset with one row and one column to add in the new sheet.